# What is the meaning of sequence in java?

Tags: java, multithreading

Java Thread can have begining,end and sequence,What does that mean?

Comment: It means nothing without any context. It sounds like you're reading a bad book or tutorial. If you give us the context we *may* be able to infer the meaning from the surrounding text.

Comment: http://www.cs.nccu.edu.tw/~linw/javadoc/tutorial/java/threads/definition.html

Comment: http://prasanta-paul.blogspot.in/2011/06/multi-threaded-execution-control.html

Comment: Everything that has a beginning has an end. - The Matrix Revolutions

Comment: I associated this with 'sequence diagram', a UML (Unified Modeling Language) diagram which represents multi-threaded behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I think all it means is that a thread executes a sequence of actions. It's expressing that concept pretty badly, to be honest.

In other words:

- You create a `Thread`, ideally passing it a `Runnable`. (You can extend `Thread` instead and override its `run` method but that's generally frowned upon.)
- You call `start` on it
- The thread which called `start` continues executing the next statement in its program
- The `run` method executes in the separate thread, independently of the thread that started it. The behaviour in here is what I believe is meant by the "sequence"
- The new thread eventually ends due to one of the following conditions:

  - Its `run` method completes normally
  - Its `run` method completes with an exception
  - If it's a *daemon* thread, it can terminate as part of the JVM terminating due to all the *non-daemon* thread exiting